# React-Bootstrap Carousel not functioning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I'm using the React-Bootstrap framework ([link](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/)) and trying to use the [Carousel](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/components/carousel/) component. For whatever reason, it's [showing up funky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yda2f.jpg). It's doing its job and transitioning between slides, but it's definitely not supposed to look how it does, so I'm missing something.

I'm currently importing the latest version of Bootstrap, and I also tried importing just version 3 since I read that on another solution with a similar issue. Tried importing the react-bootstrap js file just in case. Tried wrapping it in a Container and tried removing it from the  just in case they were (for whatever reason) conflicting with one another. I also tried just using plain Bootstrap and had the same issue.

I feel like at this point, I might just need another set of eyes because I'm probably missing something silly.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";
import Row from "react-bootstrap/Row";
import Col from "react-bootstrap/Col";
import Jumbotron from "react-bootstrap/Jumbotron";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Carousel from "react-bootstrap/Carousel";
import {
  FontAwesomeIcon
} from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

class Main extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // See HTML section
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

```html
<main>
  <section id="testimonials" className="p-5">
    <Carousel>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src="holder.js/800x400?text=First slide&bg=373940" alt="First slide" />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>
            Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.
          </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src="holder.js/800x400?text=Second slide&bg=282c34" alt="Third slide" />

        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img className="d-block w-100" src="holder.js/800x400?text=Third slide&bg=20232a" alt="Third slide" />

        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: looks like it working but you're expecting it to be full-height? Check the size of your `<section>` tag

Comment: @vicodin It's not loading any of the images it provides with it though, and the text is off to the left side. Also, the Carousel.Caption's aren't showing at all.

Comment: It's hard to help you from just using a code snippet which I can't run and having a screenshot. Any way to reproduce it on the sandbox or maybe you have a live version of this page? I bet it's a styling issue, not Carousel's one

Comment: @vicodin Sure! You can check it out here: https://madelinejones.github.io/cyobeauty/

Comment: Ok I see. Images aren't working because holder.js is not replacing it's src URLs with proper links. 
Btw, you can use something like picsum.photos for same goals without a need of additional packages to mock images to avoid such problems (It will also remove 404 errors from console).

Can you try this and confirm if problem remains?

Comment: You can create a quick react snippet on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) and share the link here, that will help to preview your code and solve the issue.

Comment: @flppv Sorry I never responded - our house got broken into and they stole my laptop. Your solution worked, thanks!